# PropertyChangeSupport fired event not arriving

Tags: java, model-view-controller, events

So to start off I have a model class called rit (ride) which extends the AbstractModel.
I also have an AbstractController.

The model is supposed to fire a propertychange which the abstractcontroller should handle. The event is fired correctly however it is not caught by the controller.

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel {

/**
 * Convenience class that allow others to observe changes to the model properties
 */
protected PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

/**
 * Default constructor. Instantiates the PropertyChangeSupport class.
 */
public AbstractModel() {
    propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
}

/**
 * Adds a property change listener to the observer list.
 * @param l The property change listener
 */
public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}
/**
 * Fires an event to all registered listeners informing them that a property in
 * this model has changed.
 * @param propertyName The name of the property
 * @param oldValue The previous value of the property before the change
 * @param newValue The new property value after the change
 */
protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
    PropertyChangeListener[] listener = propertyChangeSupport.getPropertyChangeListeners();


    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
}
}
```

.

```
public class RitAanvraagController extends AbstractController {

//  Properties this controller expects to be stored in one or more registered models

public static final String RITAANVRAAG_WACHTRIJ_PROPERTY = "Ritaanvraag";

/**
 * Voeg een ritaanvraag toe aan het model
 * @param ritAanvraag de nieuwe rit aanvraag.
 */
public void nieuwRitaanvraag(RitAanvraagModel ritAanvraag) {
    alterModelProperty("add", RITAANVRAAG_WACHTRIJ_PROPERTY, ritAanvraag);
}
}
```

.

```
package com.itopia.railcabserver.controller;

public abstract class AbstractController implements PropertyChangeListener {

//  Vectors that hold a list of the registered models and views for this controller.
private ArrayList<AbstractViewPanel> registeredViews;
private ArrayList<AbstractModel> registeredModels;

/** Creates a new instance of Controller */
public AbstractController() {
    registeredViews = new ArrayList<AbstractViewPanel>();
    registeredModels = new ArrayList<AbstractModel>();
}

/**
 * Binds a model to this controller. Once added, the controller will listen for all 
 * model property changes and propogate them on to registered views. In addition,
 * it is also responsible for resetting the model properties when a view changes
 * state.
 * @param model The model to be added
 */
public void addModel(AbstractModel model) {
    registeredModels.add(model);
    model.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}


public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

    for (AbstractViewPanel view : registeredViews) {
        view.modelPropertyChange(evt);
    }
}
}
```

The method propertyChange is never in the abstractcontroller, is never fired.

but when i fire this: propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue); in the abstractmodel the propertychange never gets fired in the abstractcontroller. not when i print something to the console nor when i set a breakpoint. 
When i debug and set a breakpoint at the method propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
the PropertyChangeListener[] listener does contain the ritAanvraagController. So it should be fired to it, then being handled by the abstractcontroller.

I hope anyone sees my mistake and can help me out.

Kind Regards,
Rikkert

Comment: firePropertyChange only fires an event if the old value is different from the new one. Use the debugger to see if it really fires an event, and follow the method calls to see what happens to the event.